# represent "there is X where a(X) is not true" and alike in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

let's say I have some predicate `a/1`, now how would I represent `b` which is `true` if `a` fails for some value ?

Unfortunately `not` doesn't help here , a definition like this :

```
b(X):- not(a(X)).
```

means "b is true if for any X a is false"(I want this to work when `X` isn't instantiated).

How would someone express this ? and what about the general case where more than one (not instantiated) variable exists ?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't know how to determine good candidates for `X`. How is the universe of all available `X` where `a(X)` is or isn't true determined? You need something to tell. For example, `b(X) :- valid(X), not(a(X)).` where `valid(X)` is true for *any* value of `X` that is a candidate to test against `not(a(X))`. You can use any filter you wish for `valid(X)`, but it must be able to produce `X`.

Comment: Said differently, `not(a(X))` (which should be `\+ a(X)` to be ISO compliant) [succeeds if `a(X)` is not provable](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1). So if there is *any* value of `X` for which `a(X)` can succeed, then `\+ a(X)` will fail. But if `X` had a specific instantiation or was otherwise constrained within a domain for which `a(X)` is not provable, then `\+ a(X)` would succeed. For example, if you had facts `a(1). a(2)`, then `X #> 2, \+ a(X).` will succeed, but just `a(X)` will fail. If there were no facts or rules making `a(X)` true, then `\+ a(X)` fails.

Comment: @lurker thank you very much, you have solved my problem :) I think you should answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there more *known* about `a/1`?

Many Prolog predicates *do* have purely relational, *sound* negations.

For example, the **unification** `X = Y` can be cleanly stated **not** to hold by using the constraint `dif/2`: `dif(X, Y)` is true **iff** `X` and `Y` are *different*. It works correctly in all modes of use.

Similarly, CLP(FD) constraints like `(#=)/2`, `(#>)/2` and others all have a completely sound logical negations. For example, you can say `X #\= Y` to state that `X` and `Y` are **distinct** integers.

A general way to express such issues is to *reify* the truth values of your predicates. For example, instead of a predicate `a/1`, consider a predicate `a/2`, where the second argument denotes **whether** the predicate holds in this case. You would call this as `a(Arg, Truth)`, and your job is to implement it in such a way that `Truth` correctly reflects the truth value of `a/1` for `Arg`. You can throw an `instantiation_error` in cases where you cannot make a sound decision. The preferable way is of course to declaratively express all possible cases using suitable constraints.

In some cases, constraint refication is already available out of the box. For example, you can negate all *reifable* CLP(FD) constraints using the predicate `(#\)/1`. Therefore, `#\ (X #= Y)` is the same as `X #\= Y`. Boolean constraints provide similar features.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed before, **there is no logical negation** in Prolog, since there is no closed universe. Prolog negation is a negation-by-failure. This is, something is false whether it can not be prooved to be true.

In practique, not/1 (or '\+'/1) requieres a ground term to behalf as a logical negation.

You may find some experiments with logical negation (closed universes or domains) in some development environments (as far as I remember, Ciao Prolog has something about that). It requieres variables to be declared as having values at some finite domain.

Comment: In addition to my explanation: ¿have you noted that there is a predefined true/0 predicate, but not a false/0?. However, there is a fail/0 predicate...

Comment: `false/0` is even in the Prolog ISO standard! All conformant systems have it.

Comment: You are right. But false/0 is not predefined (built-in,I mean), just part of a library (which may have been preloaded or not). fail/0 is a virtual machine's primitive (built-in).